# Not going to next activity when clicking on item in listview.

Tags: android, listviewitem, sqlite

I am new to android, using sqlite to insert data in database, and use these data on custom list view. The problem occurs when I edit the data with edit button in next activity show the row string but, in every row edit but show the data of 1st row string..
 by image u can esily understand:
[image]

I want the row name in new activity page while i click on edit..
delete row when i press delete .. help me..

editlist java file

```
public class EditLIST extends Activity {


    private AndroidSQLite mySQLiteAdapter ;
final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "edit.list.message";
 public void onClick (View view) {


     Intent intent = new Intent (this,display.class);
     TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     String message=textView.getText().toString();


     //data.putString("thetext",text);
     intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
     startActivity(intent);
}
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_list);
        ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);



        mySQLiteAdapter = new AndroidSQLite(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
      mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();

       mySQLiteAdapter.insert("umesh");
       mySQLiteAdapter.insert("kalpesh");
       mySQLiteAdapter.insert("manish");


        mySQLiteAdapter.close();

        mySQLiteAdapter = new AndroidSQLite(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

        Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[]{AndroidSQLite.KEY_FNAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textView1};




        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
         new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.button, cursor, from, to);


                  listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);



    }


    }
```

AndroidSQLite.java file

package edit.list;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class AndroidSQLite {

public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "abncd";
public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "zxc";
public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_FNAME = "FNAME";



//create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
"create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
+ KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ KEY_FNAME + " text not null);";

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

private Context context;

public AndroidSQLite(Context c){
context = c;
}

public AndroidSQLite openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
return this;
}

public AndroidSQLite openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
}

public void close(){
sqLiteHelper.close();
}

public long insert(String fname){

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put(KEY_FNAME, fname);

return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}

public int deleteAll(){
return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}

public Cursor queueAll(){
String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME};
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
  null, null, null, null, null);

return cursor;
}

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
  CursorFactory factory, int version) {
 super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}

}
```

display.java

```
public class display extends Activity {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.display);


                // Get the message from the intent
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String message = intent.getStringExtra(EditLIST.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

                // Create the text view
                EditText editText = new EditText(this);
                editText.setTextSize(40);
                editText.setText(message);

                // Set the text view as the activity layout
                setContentView(editText);
                }
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_edit_list,menu);
            return true;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure If I understand you correctly. As I understood when you click edit you always get the data from the first item regardless of which item you actually clicked? In that case I think the problem is here :

```
TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

You're searching for R.id.textView1 in the whole list and only the first item is being returned. You need to search only within the item clicked :

```
TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Where view is the parameter to the onClick function.

As I said I'm not sure if that was the question but it looks like a problem.

Comment: on the place of textview , i cant use the listview ,
so please by position how can i contrl every edit button of row

Comment: Perhaps, AndroidSQLite should extend ListActivity rather than just Activity and override onListItemClick. Might need a bit of work but it's the easiest way in the end. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)

Comment: my textview doubt is clear , but how a delete a single row..from listview with deletebutton..

Answer (score 0):

i think you have  a problem with your delete code
it will be like..

public int delete_byID(int id)
        {
             sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE,KEY_ROWID + "=" +1,null) ;
             return -1;
        }

that will delete id number 1 from the table